# Magento 1.9 Images missing in fronted

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, products

I copied a site from one domain to another.  On new site, images are missing on Web-Pages. I can see the images in back end.

I cleaned all caches in

```
Admin > Configuration > Cache Management
```

and Reindexed data from **Index Management**.

Still images are missing from product page. I have gd installed on the server. I tried uploading a new image, that shows properly. Only problem is with old images.

Comment: Whar are the urls for not working images? Maybe try to "
Flush Catalog Images Cache" from Cache Management. Or maybe some rights problem. Any info in logs?

Comment: Here is a product in front end (https://i.imgur.com/dC3Zu43.png). Same product in admin area (https://i.imgur.com/kZkl2Mx.png). I tried cleaning cache in admin area, rebuild index. Also tried deleting media/catalog/product/cache folder. I don't see any error in log file. There is only 1 log file in var/log folder, system.log, do i need to enable some other logs ? All permissions are set proper, 777 (also running under php-fpm on cpanel server, so not a permission issue, cache folders get created if i delete them).

Comment: Strange. I see placeholder/image.jpg. Looks like media files are not correctly set. Did you tried to do full reindex and cache clear again?

Comment: I got it resolved, problem was with memory,  increasing PHP memory limit fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by memory_limit. Increasing memory_limit fixed the problem.